# Server push to c# client in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, comet

Is there any way to implement server push from GAE to c# client? I found channel-api is available only for Javascript applications & also GAE is not supporting comet solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not currently any supported mechanism of doing client push to anything other than a Javascript client, unless you use an external service to do it.

Comment: That's a sad thing. It may be better if I can use my Java client for channel-api. Hope google will work for it soon.